# glCreateProgram causes segfault?

Tags: objective-c, macos, opengl, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to write a Wavefront OBJ file viewer in Objective-C, that is capable of loading meshes/materials/shaders from files. I've created classes for shaders and shader programs, and I'm trying to create an OpenGL shader program object as part of my shader program class's init method:

```
- (id)initWithVertexShader:(NSString *)vshader FragmentShader:(NSString *)fshader {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    SRShader* shaders[2] = {
        [[SRShader alloc] initWithFilename:vshader Type:GL_VERTEX_SHADER Source:nil],
        [[SRShader alloc] initWithFilename:fshader Type:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER Source:nil]
    };

    program = glCreateProgram();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        SRShader* s = shaders[i];
        NSError* e = nil;
        s.source = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:s.filename encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&e];
        if (!e) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to read shader file: %@\n", s.filename);
            exit(-1);
        }

        GLuint shader = [s compile];
... and so on.
```

However, calling glCreateProgram results in EXC_BAD_ACCESS, as does the call to [SRShader compile], which in turn calls glCreateShader. Does anyone know of any issues with these function calls in Objective-C? Maybe something to do with ARC or calling them in an initialization function?

Comment: Have you first created an OpenGL context and made it current on the calling thread?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using an NSOpenGLView, you will need to add the following lines of code before you ever call `glCreateProgram()`, so probably in `-(id)initWithCoder` if you load the view from Interface Builder:

```
NSOpenGLContext* context = [self openGLContext];

[context makeCurrentContext];
```

Very basic, and I know this thread is dated, but maybe it will save someone a minute or two when they Google and find this thread (as I did just now).

Comment: not that it helped me, but i think your effort should be acknoledge

Answer (score 1):

As Trevor Answered in another post you should initialize the glew.

```
glewInit();
```

source of the answer:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/22788